# Find object next to select

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I need to find the object next to the select.  These objects are created dynamically so I need to return the type of element. In the example a Label is next to the selects but it could be an input, img, etc.  The turning off slider event works fine, but I can't nail down the selector.

I have tried:

```
$( "#popupPadded" ).bind({
    popupafterclose: function (event, ui) {
        $(".flip_mini").val('off').slider('refresh');

        var $label = $(this).next();
        alert($label.text());

    }
});
```

Here is the ul...

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" >
        <li>
        <select class="flip_mini" id="flip-mini" data-role="slider" data-mini="true">
            <option value="off">close</option>
            <option value="on">open</option>
        </select>
        <label>First:</label>
        </li>

        <li>
        <select class="flip_mini" data-role="slider" data-mini="true">
            <option value="off">close</option>
            <option value="on">open</option>
        </select>
        <label>Last:</label>
        </li>

    </ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Label` is `next` to the `select with class flip_mini` so use it instead of using $(this) which has the object on which method is called.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MJ4bW/)**

```
var $label = $(".flip_mini").next();
```

As you have two select so you can get the one you require using index like this

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MJ4bW/1/)**

```
var $label1 = $(".flip_mini").eq(0).next();

var $label2 = $(".flip_mini").eq(1).next();
```

Comment: alert($label.text()); returns the closeopencloseopen texts in the select.

Comment: var $label = $(".flip_mini").next().next(); does the trick.  Thanks Adil for steering me in the right direction.

Comment: I have updated my answer with live demo, it is returning text in label.

Comment: You have two select with class flip_mini, you need to filter out which one you need, you may use id or index.

Comment: Actually yeah, it's not quite working.  So if i click a slider it should return First and then if I select the other I get the Last label.

Comment: Updated my answer this would help you to find the one you need.